# Cannot convert value of type 'JSQPhotoMediaItem?' to expected argument type 'String?'

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement JSQMessageViewController with Firebase in Xcode (Swift).

I get an error: **Cannot convert value of type 'JSQPhotoMediaItem?' to expected argument type 'String?'** from this code below:

```
func observeMessages() {
    messageRef.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        //print(snapshot.value)
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let mediaType = dict["MediaType"] as! String
            let senderId = dict["senderId"] as! String
            let senderName = dict["senderName"] as! String

            switch mediaType {

            case "TEXT":
                let text = dict["text"] as! String
                self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, text: text))
            case "PHOTO":
                let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as! String
                let url = NSURL(string: fileUrl)
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
                let picture = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                let photo = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: picture)
                self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, text: photo))

            default:
                print("unknown data type")
            }
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31688224/1531971

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should change `text` to `media` in the initializer of `JSQMessage`:

```
self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: photo))
```

FYI, `JSQMessagesViewController` is **deprecated**. [See this blog post for more information.](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/officially-deprecating-jsqmessagesviewcontroller/)

Comment: ok thank you! it solved the problem, too bad about the JSQMessagesViewController news thought :(